# Show that $f(x) = -\ln(x)$ is convex (WITHOUT using second derivative!)

Tags: convex-analysis

In the lecture notes for a course I'm taking, the definition of a convex function is given as follows:

"a function $f$ is convex if, for any $x_1$ and $x_2$, and for any $\alpha$ $\in$ [0,1], $\alpha f(x_1) + (1-\alpha)f(x_2) \ge f(\alpha x_1 + (1-\alpha ) x_2)$"

That is, if you draw a line segment between two points on the curve for this function, the function evaluated at any $x$ between $x_1$ and $x_2$ will be lower than the line segment.

Immediately after this definition is given, there is an exercise: "show that $f(x) = -\ln(x)$ is convex." Now, I happen to know that a function is convex if its second derivative is always greater than zero, so we can easily check the second derivative here to show that $-\ln(x)$ is convex (the second derivative is $\frac{1}{x^2}$, which is always greater than zero).

However, because of the way the exercise comes immediately after the "line segment" definition of convexity, without any mention of the second derivative test, I get the impression that it is possible to prove that $-\ln(x)$ is convex without using the second derivative test. I have attacked this problem many different ways, and I haven't been able to show convexity using only the line segment definition. Is this possible?

Comment: You might find a useful answer here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/216705/prove-ax-x-logx-is-convex

Comment: $g(\alpha)=RHS-LHS=0$ for $\alpha=0,1$. Show that $g'(\alpha)$ changes sign only once.

Comment: @A.S. The OP is requesting no second derivatives.  The approach you suggest is along an analogous line.  In fact, we can use the weighted AM-GM and arrive at the result immediately.  ;-)) - Mark

Comment: @Dr.MV I am using only the first derivative ;) True to the letter - not the spirit.

Comment: @A.S. Yes, I understand.  And maybe this will suffice the OP's needs.  It seemed that the OP was seeking a way that relied only on the definition as it states in the post that all that is given is the definition - nothing more.  - Mark

Comment: @Mark Of course weighted AM-GM is more in the spirit of the question and only uses continuity of functions - not touching differentiability at all. I just didn't think of it first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the AGM nor the weighted AGM inequality. It suffices to consider the case $x> y$ and $a=\alpha \in (0,1).$ Take a fixed $y>0$ and a fixed $a\in (0,1)$ and for $x>0$ let $$g(x)=-a\log x- (1-a)\log y +\log (a x+(1-a)y).$$  We have $$g'(x)= \frac{dg(x)}{dx} = -\frac{a}{x} + \frac{a}{a x+(1-a) y} = \frac{a(1-a)(x-y)}{ax+(1-a)y}\cdot \frac {1}{x}.$$ Observe that $g'(y)=0$ and that $x>y\implies g'(x)>0.$ Therefore $$x>y\implies g(x)>g(y)=0.$$

Comment: I was referring to the bit you fixed in the edit yesterday. Everything's correct now.

Answer (score 7):

It's expedient to apply the following result (see for example, Exercise $24$, Chapter $4$ of Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*)

> If $f$ is continuous in $(a, b)$ such that 
>   $$f\left(\frac{x + y}{2}\right) \leq \frac{1}{2}f(x) + \frac{1}{2}f(y)$$
>   for all $x, y \in (a, b)$, then $f$ is convex in $(a, b)$.

Notice that $(a, b)$ can be extended to $(0, +\infty)$.

Here, if $x, y \in (0, + \infty)$, by AM-GM inequality,
$$-\ln\left(\frac{1}{2}x + \frac{1}{2}y\right) \leq -\ln(\sqrt{xy}) = \frac{1}{2}(-\ln x) + \frac{1}{2}(-\ln y).$$
Since $-\ln x$ is continuous in $(0, +\infty)$, the proof is complete.

Answer (score 5):

The [Weighted AM-GM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means#Weighted_AM.E2.80.93GM_inequality) states

$$\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y\ge x^{\lambda}y^{1-\lambda}$$

Therefore, we have

$$\log(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y)\ge \log(x^{\lambda}y^{1-\lambda})=\lambda \log(x)+(1-\lambda)\log(y)$$

Therefore the logarithm function is concave and its negative is convex.

Comment: This is circular, because Weighted AM-GM uses Jensen's applied to $\log$.

Comment: @A.S. See [HERE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality#Proof_1_.28finite_form.29) for a proof without any discussion of logarithms.  ;-))  - Mark